# Linear decision function (classification)

Tags: classification, function

Although I know some basics of linear classification, I do have some questions about the formalism. In our script, a binary linear classifier $F$ is defined as follows:
$$
F(x) = \textrm{sign}\left(\langle w, x \rangle + b\right) \in \{-1, 1\}
$$
where
$$
\textrm{sign}(z) = \begin{cases}1 \hspace{8.5mm} \textrm{ if } z \geq 0 \\ -1 \hspace{5mm} \textrm{ o.w.} \end{cases}
$$

for the weight vector $w$, the intercept $b$, and $\langle.,.\rangle$ being the dot product.

My questions:

(1) What exactly do we need the bias $b$ here for? As far as I understand, we multiply the weight vector w with the feature vector x, obtaining a scalar, which we then compare to a threshold. Hence the only use I see here in the including an intercept is to set that threshold to zero (as is actually done above) - is my understanding correct? In fact, if we always compare a scalar to a threshold, is the entire problem not reducible to the real line?

(2) Parameterization: It is stated that due to the fact that we can normalize the weight vector to have norm 1, the function has only $d$ parameters (in contrast to the weight vector not being normalized, where we would have $d+1$ parameters). Is this because the last entry of the weight vector would be determined through the normalization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Think about what would happen if we didn't have $b$: our classifier would be $F(x) = \textrm{sign}(w^T x)$ which always goes through the origin. This will severely limit the patterns that we can separate.

In the example below, we can see that the data are linearly separable, but any line going through the origin will do a very bad job. It seems absurd to restrict ourselves to such lines, so what we do is we translate all of our points over by subtracting $b$, and then a line through the origin can indeed separate them.

[image]

(2) you are correct. Let's say we've got a vector $x := (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \mathbb R^4$. Just based on that, the values in $x$ are unconstrained, i.e. we have 4 parameters that we are free to vary. But if now we know that $x^T x = 1$, then this means that $x_4^2 = 1 - x_1^2 - x_2^2 - x_3^2$ so we now only have three quantites which can be varied since the fourth is determined by the other three.

**Update**

You asked about whether or not we can get the same decision boundary with or without an intercept by modifying $w$. I'll answer that in detail here. One important thing to remember about this is that we need the values to match up for all $n$ observations, not just for a single observation.

So let $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times p}$ be our data matrix and let $(w, b) \in \mathbb R^{p+1}$ be the vector normal to our hyperplane and the intercept (i.e. the usual $w$ and $b$). I'll let $\vec b$ denote the vector in $\mathbb R^n$ of all $b$.

We want to find a vector $w^* \in \mathbb R^p$ such that $Xw + \vec b = Xw^*$. This is equivalent to solving the system
$$
X(w^* - w) = \vec b.
$$
Now we can see that if $X$ has a constant column (or just if it has a constant vector in its span) there exists a vector $v$ such that $Xv = \vec b$, i.e. $\vec b$ is in its column space and we can indeed just work with $\langle w^*, x \rangle$.

But in general we often have $n >> p$ so the span of the columns of $X$ is far less than $R^n$ and there's no reason why $\vec b$ should be in there. That means that in general we cannot exactly mimic the behavior of $\langle w, x \rangle + b$ with some other $\langle w^*, x \rangle$ unless we specifically modify our $X$ to guarantee that this is possible, such as by appending a constant column.

Comment: Many thanks - I completely understand your answer visually, but I don't do so analytically. So what I mean is the following: If we have <w,x> + b, this returns us a scalar - *but*, can't we end up with the same set of scalars just by multiplying w and x (though we would have to have other values of w)? I don't see where I am going wrong in my thought process, since this kind of doesn't match your illustration. Let me know if my question is not clear yet..thank you:)

Comment: @TestGuest I've just added an update that i hope addresses your question. If it doesn't, let me know

Comment: Thank you, I think I understood your explanation, but maybe I have to start from a more basic point, i.e. in my script, b is not a vector but just a scalar. So, <w,x> + b is nothing else than (in the case of my script) a real number. As I assume that z = <w,x> + b, and z seems to be scalar which we compare to zero, I was wondering if this in fact is not just a problem on the real line. Is the problem hence that in fact b is a vector?

Comment: @TestGuest In my answer $b$ is everywhere a scalar and $\vec b = (b, \dots, b)$ is the $n$-dimensional vector with $\vec b_i = b$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$. $\langle w, x \rangle + b$ is indeed a scalar. $w$ is the vector normal to our hyperplane (the decision boundary), so $\langle w, x \rangle$ gives the magnitude of the vector resulting from the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $w$. After shifting by $b$, the sign tells us if we're above the decision boundary or below it, i.e. which class we are in. What do you mean by a 'problem on the real line'?

Comment: What I mean with "a problem on the real line" is that we always compare a scalar to a threshold - depending if it is above or below the threshold we classify into one or the other group. Hence the entire linear classification can be reduced onto a 1-dimensional problem (again, just the comparison of a scalar (<w,x>+b) to another scalar (the threshold))..right?

Comment: @TestGuest you do make your decision by comparing two scalars but I don't think that's a very useful reduction.  If I told you to find a function $f : \mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) > b$ is a good classifier, you could just choose $f$ to perfectly classify the data every time. It has no structure. If we impose the requirement that actually $f$ is determined by a parameter vector $w$ and $f(x) = \langle x, w \rangle$ now we have structure and can avoid overfitting (we've now reduced the complexity of the set of functions that we are considering so we have a chance of learning well).

Comment: @TestGuest you're very welcome, I'm glad this was helpful